# Alternative of target=_blank to be validated in XHTML 1.1?

Tags: validation, xhtml, new-window

I'm trying to validate my website with XHTML and I've fixed lots of errors but some errors keep bothering me. What is the alternative for target="_blank" to be use in below code

```
    if($targetwindow==0){

        $openWindow='class="colorbox"';

    }elseif ($targetwindow==1){

        $openWindow='target=_self';     

    }else{

        $openWindow='target="_blank"';  

    }

echo '<a style="color:#555;" '.$openWindow.' href="'.$items["mylink"].'" '.($nofollow==1 ? 'rel="nofollow"':'').'>'.$items["mytitle"].'.....</a><br />';'
```

I tried using `onclick="window.open(this.href, 'OffSite').focus(); return false;` in header.php for linking facebook urls to new windows and it works like a charm but I'm unable to do this in the above code. Can anyone help me with regards to that? Or perhaps the same code will work but I don't know that how to give it in the proper format since I already tried that. I've read related threads about my question and I also found the answer such as `onclick="return !window.open(this.href)"` but the problem is where to put? I tried putting and it makes the website down. Kindly help!

Comment: Why are you trying to validate your website as XHTML 1.1? Is it really XHTML? Do you send a `header("Content-type: application/xhtml+xml");` from the PHP? If not, it's just HTML and you can use the `target` attribute.

Comment: Otherwise, `target="_self"` would cause the same validation problems as `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 0):

An option for what you want is using a script like this:

```
    /*
 *  variables
*/
var object_links_list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var links_total = object_links_list.length;





/*
 *  listenners
*/
for ( n = 0; n < links_total; n++ ) {
    if ( "rel" in object_links_list[n] ) {
        if ( object_links_list[n].rel === "external" ) {
            if ( object_links_list[n].addEventListener ) {
                object_links_list[n].addEventListener( 'click', open_external_link, false );
            } else if ( object_links_list[n].attachEvent ) {
                object_links_list[n].attachEvent( 'click', open_external_link );
            }
        }
    }
}





/*
 *  Function to open links in a new window/tab
*/
function open_external_link() {
    window.open( this.href, '_blank' );
    this.setAttribute('href','');
    if ( this.stopPropagation ) {
        this.stopPropagation();
    } else {
        this.cancelBubble = true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And the xhtml would be something like this.

```
    <a href="http://www.example.com/" title="your_title" rel="external">link text</a>
```